# D3 v5 zoom limit pan

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to limit pan in d3 zoom but I am not getting correct results. I am using following code to extent both `scale` and `translate`.

```
var treeGroup = d3.select('.treeGroup');
var rootSVG = d3.select('.rootSVG')
var zoom = d3.zoom()
     .scaleExtent([1.6285, 3])
     .translateExtent([[0, 0],[800, 600]])
     .on('zoom', function(){
           treeGroup.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
     })

rootSVG.call(zoom);
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nohe76yd/45/

`scaleExtent` works fine but `translateExtent` is giving issues. How do I specify correct value for `translateExtent` so that while panning content always stays inside the `svg` container?

Comment: the translate extent depends on the zoom/scale factor. In the on-zoom function modify the transform by using Math.min and Math.max. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563890/9938317

Answer (score 2):

The translateExtent works best when used dynamically to the graph group you're using. It takes two arguments: `topLeft` and `bottomRight`, which are x and y coordinates each.

In my example, I recalculate the extent based on the graph's size, with the help of `getBBox()` and adding some margins. Take a look, it might help you: https://bl.ocks.org/agnjunio/fd86583e176ecd94d37f3d2de3a56814

**EDIT:** Adding the code that does this to make easier to read, inside zoom function.

```
// Define some world boundaries based on the graph total size
// so we don't scroll indefinitely
const graphBox = this.selections.graph.node().getBBox();
const margin = 200;
const worldTopLeft = [graphBox.x - margin, graphBox.y - margin];
const worldBottomRight = [
    graphBox.x + graphBox.width + margin,
    graphBox.y + graphBox.height + margin
];
this.zoom.translateExtent([worldTopLeft, worldBottomRight]);
```

Comment: I am tying to do this, to avoid infinite panning to left (x-axis) but .getBBox() is returning all zero values. x,y, width and height. could you please help on this